# How do I interprete a record returned as a NSAppleScript result

Tags: objective-c, applescript, appleevents, applescript-objc

I run an applescript from an objective-c application using NSAppleScript the executeAndReturnError method. This returns an NSAppleEventDescriptor object containing the result of the script. My script returns an applescript record. How do interpret the record in objective-c? For instance if the returned script record is { name:"Jakob", phone:"12345678" } how do I get the string "Jakob" in the name property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method to convert the record to a dictionary. Note that I didn't try this but it should work.

Also, your "name" key is not a good key to use in applescript because "name" has other meanings to applescript. I've often had problems using that in a record. I would suggest changing it something like "theName" or using it in bars |name|.

```
-(NSDictionary*)recordToDictionary:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)theDescriptor {
    NSUInteger j,count;
    id thisDescriptor = [theDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:1];
    count = [thisDescriptor numberOfItems];
    NSMutableDictionary* thisDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:count/2];
    for (j=0; j<count; j=j+2) {
        NSString* theKey = [[thisDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:(j+1)] stringValue];
        NSString* theVal = [[thisDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:(j+2)] stringValue];
        [thisDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theVal forKey:theKey]];
    }
    return (NSDictionary*)[[thisDictionary retain] autorelease];
}
```

Of course after the record is in dictionary format you can just use the "valueForKey:" instance method on the dictionary to get "Jacob".

Comment: It works, thanks! Where do you find documentation about this stuff?

Comment: Btw: I suppose the retain / autorelease in the last line is not really necessary as the dictionaryWithCapacity is already returning an autoreleasing object - ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I learned this stuff just by googling and experimentation. I use a lot of applescript stuff in my code so I had to learn it. The last retain/autorelease stuff is just a precaution. Sometimes autoreleased objects are released too soon when you return them from a method, so this just makes sure the value sticks around a little longer so it isn't released before you're done with it. It's not necessary but just a precaution. Note that this dictionary is also autoreleased so there's no need for you to release it in your code... unless you retain it of course.

Comment: Any change to get an updated version of this for Swift? Unfortunately wasn’t able to translate it and having a really hard time to figure it out :(