# Convert AppleScript response to JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, applescript

I have a Cocoa application, part of it takes AppleScript from the user in a web view. I currently can pass a single string from a command (e.g. the current iTunes song name), however, if I run a command that returns a record (I believe that's what it is based on my research, could be wrong) such as the below I get '(null)' as the stringValue.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get properties of current track
end tell
```

If I run this in Script Debugger I can get this as a table shown below, so it's clearly possible. 
[image]

However, nothing I've tried seems to be working. Based on a number of SO answers I've tried different ways, such as looping over every descriptor index as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180653/how-do-i-interprete-a-record-returned-as-a-nsapplescript-result). However, this doesn't work anymore, as it seems the key is not included in the array.

So, basically, I need to be able to convert an AppleScript output to JSON. I have a serialiser so that's not the issue, as long as I can get them in to Cocoa objects I'm set. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many months late as an answer, but in case you or anyone else cares, here is what I did with a similar problem.

Check out the (sadly defunct) [AppScript framework](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/objc-appscript/index.html). That combined with lightly modified SBJSON let me convert any AppleScript record into JSON via Cocoa objects.

I used it in [JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net) which is free on the Mac AppStore. You can also see the source to an earlier version on Google code [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-helper/), which might be useful if you want to use the modified version of SBJSON.

In my example below the AppleScript record is being supplied via a scripting command.

```
@implementation makeJSONFromRecord


- (id)performDefaultImplementation {

    NSDictionary    *asRecord;
    NSString        *result;
    AEMCodecs       *codecs = [[AEMCodecs alloc] init];


    // Use appscript framework to unpack the event into an object we can use

    asRecord =[codecs unpack:[self directParameter]];
    [codecs release];

    // Use the JSON framework to convert the object to JSON notation

    result = [asRecord JSONRepresentation];

    if (result==nil) {

    //We failed to create any valid JSON so return nothing
        NSLog(@"Failed to make JSON from: %@", asRecord);
        result=@"";
    }

    // Return the result to the applescript

    return result;

}

@end
```

Comment: I know it's been ages since I asked this question and this answer was given, but I've tested this and it does indeed work. Thanks!